# Center SWF in Browser

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

```
    I have my application developed in Flex 4. I want the application to fit in the browser because at the moment the screen centers horizontally but the vertically it only shows around 3/4 of the application.

I believe I need to modify in index.template.html

 I did it as follows by setting width and height to 100% but it does not seem to work.



    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <html lang="en">

    <!-- 
    Smart developers always View Source. 

    This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
    for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
    Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

    Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
    // -->

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
    <!--  END Browser History required section -->

    <title>${title}</title>
    <script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>

    <!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
    <script src="history/history.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <!--  END Browser History required section -->

    <style>
    body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Globals
    // Major version of Flash required
    var requiredMajorVersion = ${version_major};
    // Minor version of Flash required
    var requiredMinorVersion = ${version_minor};
    // Minor version of Flash required
    var requiredRevision = ${version_revision};
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body scroll="no">
    <div id="flashContent" align="center">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    // Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)
    var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

    // Version check based upon the values defined in globals
    var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

    if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
        // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
        // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
        var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
        var MMredirectURL = window.location;
        document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
        var MMdoctitle = document.title;

        AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "playerProductInstall",
            "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
            "width", "100%",
            "height", "100%",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "${application}",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "${bgcolor}",
            "name", "${application}",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
        );
    } else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
        // if we've detected an acceptable version
        // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
        AC_FL_RunContent(
                "src", "${swf}",
                "width", "100%",
                "height", "100%",
                "align", "middle",
                "id", "${application}",
                "quality", "high",
                "bgcolor", "${bgcolor}",
                "name", "${application}",
                "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
                "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
                "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
        );
      } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
        var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
        + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
        + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
        document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
      }
    // -->
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                id="${application}" width="${width}" height="${height}"
                codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
                <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <embed src="${swf}.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="${bgcolor}"
                    width="100%" height="100%" name="${application}" align="middle"
                    play="true"
                    loop="false"
                    quality="high"
                    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                </embed>
        </object>
    </noscript>
    </body>
    </html>



Any one ha a better idea?
```

Answer (score 0):

try `width=100% height=100%` with the `object` element. It will fit the .swf in the whole the screen.

Their is no simple way to align the element vertically. You can use some javascript to calculate the window height then set the `padding` of object with the help of that value.

Kind Regards, 
Saurabh

Comment: I tried setting width and height to 100% as you said and also did same in the two places above BUT seems that this shrinks the application..lets say to around 70% as compared to its original size. Thats Strange. Any other idea?

Comment: Hi @FlexyBoz, this is happening because your `body` or the parent container has padding or margin of somekind. Try setting the  `margin: 0` and `padding:0` for `body`. This should fix your problem.